# IF statement AIX (Korn Shell Script)

Tags: ksh, aix

I've made a script which collects info.
One of the things it does is checking if a file or directory exists.
If yes, it copies it to the `/tmp` directory.

The script fails with

> 0403-057 Syntax error at line 3 : `then' is not matched.

This is the statement that fails:

```
if [ -d /etc/nginx ];
then
cp -R /etc/nginx/* /tmp/
fi
```

Comment: That looks fine to me. Check that there aren't any invisible characters like non-breaking spaces or carriage returns at line ends. `od -c script.sh` or such should tell.

Answer (score 1):

The script is fine. The error you describe most likely means you have Windows-style line endings. I can reproduce it by adding `\r` to the end of each line:

```
$ cat script.sh
if [ -d /etc/nginx ];
then
cp -R /etc/nginx/* /tmp/
fi
$ sed 's/$/\r/' script.sh 
$ ksh script.sh 
script.sh: syntax error at line 5: `if' unmatched
```

You probably edited the file on a Windows computer and that would have inserted `\r\n` line endings instead of the normal *nix `\n` line endings. Just remove them and you should be fine:

```
sed -i 's/\r//' script.sh
```

That might not work on AIX's `sed` though. If it doesn't, use this instead:

```
sed 's/\r//' script.sh  > tempFile && mv tempFile script.sh
```

Or

```
tr -d '\r' < script.sh > tempFile && mv tempFile script.sh
```